# Custom events in web components?

Tags: dart, dart-webui, web-component

I want to implement my own text input web component like:

```dart
<x-text autocomplete="{{ true }}"></x-text>
```

The thing is, when the user chooses an item from the autocompletion list, how can my web component fire an event? I'm looking for something like this:

```dart
<x-text autocomplete="{{ true }}" on-select="itemSelected()"></x-text>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no support for it: https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/issues/242

Answer (score 3):

This is possible, but maybe not very intuitive.

You can't bind to a custom event in HTML. You must do it manually in code:

```html
<x-foo id="wtvr"></x-foo>
```

```dart
_root.query('#wtvr').on['foo'].add((e) => print(e));
```

Then when the components fires the event, you just write:

```dart
_root.on['foo'].dispatch(new CustomEvent('foo'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Without having working with web components that much, from the top of my head I would just implement a onchange/onblur function for the selection itself.